# How to choose Alarm tone from library?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am new to iPhone Development.
i am trying to develop an **Alarm** application. I want to give a choice to the user to choose alarm ringtone from library like `UIImagePickerController`.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, the `UIImagePickerController` is for image only and there is not such controller for picker the ringtone.

Also if you are scheduling alarms via [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the the `soundName` property must contain a name of a sound file which is in you apps bundle.

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the application’s main bundle or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or badges an application icon, it plays this sound. The default value is nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.